# Sub-Shapefile Attribute Ineritance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, fields-attributes, envi

I have two shapefiles:

1. a shapefile of plant communities: each polygon there covers a wide swath of land and names the plant community there.
2. I also have another shapefile that identifies a bunch of tree crowns and the specie of each.

Given the polygons of the second shapefile are much smaller than the first, how can I know the plant community that each crown belongs to?

I know pretty much most object oriented programming languages, R and matlab and no knowledge of ArcGIS. ENVI.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using a [spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) in your situation to join your first shape file with your second. That would allow you to determine based on location where each of the crowns are in relation to the communities.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in R? or Matlab?

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia Unfortunately I am not too familiar with R or Matlab, so I would not be much help there.